# Markers Disappear after re-running the application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markers

Hi I am working on Google Maps and I am trying to create some onMapClick Listeners so when the user clicks on the map a marker is created. Everything is fine with that but when I close and re-run the application the markers do not exist. Is there any possible way to make the markers constant ? Any advice on that ? Many thanks.

Here is my code where the markers are created on the onmapclick event. the marker location america is created and it is constantly there to the specific latlng but why when i click on the map the markers that are added on the map dissapear after re compiling and the marker LOCATION_AMERICA is still there. please help

```
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gMap=   
               ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(LOCATION_AMERICA).
    title("AMERICA").
    snippet("Population:5.000.0000"));
    gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    configureImageButton();

             gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {



            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                    .title("HOTEL")
                    .snippet("RESTAURANT")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

        }
    });}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), such that each time you add a marker you save its `LatLng` in the **Shared Preferences**. After closing the application and open it again you will load the **Shared Preferences** and get all the saved `LatLng` and you will be able to draw your markers again.

```
      SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
//here you can load the number of markers you have
            //appSharedPrefs.getInt("MarkersCount", 0);
//then you will load the markers lat and lng by incremented id and draw the markers

// when you draw a new marker in the onMapClickListener
 gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {



                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                        .title("HOTEL")
                        .snippet("RESTAURANT")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
    // Here you will have to save lat lng in string and save it in the shared preferences with incremented id
//  then add the number of markers in the sharedPreferences.
            }
        });
```

Comment: how could I implement what you are saying ? can you refer me to any documentation please ?